# Google maps showing blank screen, earlier it was working fine but after reinstalling android studio it stopped

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to display a google maps in a very simple application. In this project i want to show user's location taking GPS location. This is the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.hamzah.locationtracker">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string 
resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to 
sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including 
the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in 
src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have a valid key in @string/google_maps_key, as i told that it was working fine earlier.
Main Activity:

```
package com.hamzah.locationtracker;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener {
    final static int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;
    final static String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,

        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};
private GoogleMap mMap;
MarkerOptions mo;
Marker marker;
LocationManager locationManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mo = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("My Current Location");
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && !isPermissionGranted()) {
        requestPermissions(PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
    } else requestLocation();
    if (!isLocationEnabled())
        showAlert(1);
}

/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    marker = mMap.addMarker(mo);
    /**
     * LatLng sydney =  new LatLng(-34,151);
     * mMap.addMarker(newMarkerOptions().positions)
     */
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    LatLng myCoordinates = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    marker.setPosition(myCoordinates);
    int zoom = 15;
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myCoordinates, zoom));
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

}

private void requestLocation() {
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_HIGH);
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 10, this);
}

private boolean isLocationEnabled() {
    return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ||
            locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
}
private boolean isPermissionGranted(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v("myLog", "Permission is Granted");
            return true;
        }else {
            Log.v("myLog", "Permission not Granted");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
    private void showAlert(final int status) {
    String message, title, btnText;
    if (status == 1) {
        message = "Your Location Setting is set to 'Off'\nPlease Enable Location to " +
                "use this app";
        title = "Enable Location";
        btnText = "Location Settings";
    } else {
        message = "Please Allow this app to access location!";
        title =  "Permission Access";
        btnText = "Grant";
    }
    final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setTitle(title)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton(btnText, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                    if (status == 1) {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(myIntent);
                    } else
                        requestPermissions(PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
    dialog.show();
    }
}
```

The layout file is untouched

This is the gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hamzah.locationtracker"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

When i execute the app i just get a screen with a blank screen and the Google logo in the left bottom corner. I am using an emulator Google XL API level 25, and also a physical device Samsung S4 API level 22.

Comment: Can you see any error message in LogCat?

Comment: No error message in LogCat

Comment: The described behavior typically happens when authentication is failing. API key is wrong, or API key doesn't have correct package or SHA1 in restriction, or you use Premium plan SDK with Standard plan API key. Anyway you should see authentication error message in your logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a new key, so you need to update it in the API console

go here: https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/api-list

- Then log in and select your project.
- Then click on `Maps SDK for Android`
- Then select the "`Credentials`" register, and then `API-key`

You will see a table like this:

[image]

and this is where you enter your SHA1 hashes. Note that if you use different signing keys for e.g. development and production, you can register multiple hashes for the same package,

Comment: It worked i requested another API key from google and then used it. But the major problem is now the app is working on emulator not on physical device

Comment: Happy it worked for you. If you install it on a physical device using an .apk file (not directly per cable in Android Studio), your .apk is probably signed by another key of your own from your own key store. You also need to register the SHA1 hash for this key in the API console

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked when i installed the apk file. Can you tell me how "to register the SHA1 hash for this key in the API console".

Comment: Thank you. I would also like to know "How to use saved instance state for maps" because every time i open the app the map starts from 0,0 position (I have set the initial position as 0,0)

Answer (score 0):

Just Regenerate the Maps Api key from console and replace the old one with the new one in your project